# Comparing two directories c#

Tags: c#

I'm looking to compare two directories. I need to compare Time modified on the files within them. Here's some pseudocode on what I want to do:

```
FOR each FILE in DIR-A
    if FILE["data-modified"] > DIR-B-Files[Date-modified] THEN
        Do Something
    Else
        Do Nothing
    Endif
```

Comment: Shouldn´t be that difficult to turn that into valid C#-code, should it? So where **specifically** are you stuck?

Comment: Your pseudo-code looks fine. Is there a question somewhere?

Comment: @elgonzo I need to do that in c#

Comment: @HimBromBeere I have no clue how to do that?

Comment: Yeah, okay. What is stopping you? Spend some time with tutorials learning C#. Then look into the clases/types provided by the System.IO namespace. There are several that might be helpful for your project.

Comment: Im looking to get this of a ftp server, would the easiest way of doing this be downloading then checking? or is the a way to do it with ftp

Comment: Spend some time with the documentation. Look what the System.IO namespace provides (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io?view=netframework-4.7.1). If you want to program in any programming language using whatever framework, you can't avoid looking into the documentation anyhow...

Comment: Just my opinion, but considering that you currently rather struggle with basic C# and/or file-related stuff, i would suggest you stay away from ftp and other networking stuff for the time being...

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help. Could you write an answer for the rep ;)

Comment: What does your question have to do with FTP?

Comment: I wanted to compare files from an ftp to a local machines files. Just forgot to write

Comment: @Kong So why did you delete the FTP tag then? - The accepted answer will not be much useful to you for FTP. Why did you accept it then?

Comment: Im going to just download the directory to temp and compare that

Comment: i am not able to  develop  the code between two directories that works as:
in Directory A I Delete or rename files and directories and after must be  reflect  in  B Directory this change.How Can I build this join  between them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method could be one way of achieving what you want.

Check that the two folders contains the same number of files.
Iterate the (sorted) files and check for name equality as well as last write time timestamp equality.

```
private bool DirectoryModificationTimeEquals(string pathA, string pathB)
{
    var directoryA = new DirectoryInfo(pathA);
    var directoryB = new DirectoryInfo(pathB);
    var filesA = directoryA.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
    var filesB = directoryB.GetFiles().OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

    if (filesA.Count == filesB.Count)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < filesA.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!filesA[i].Name.Equals(filesB[i].Name))
            {
                return false;
            }
            if (filesA[i].LastWriteTime != filesB[i].LastWriteTime)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks KaffeKopp but as wrote  above :i am not able to develop the code between two directories that works as: in Directory A I Delete or rename files and directories and after must be reflect in B Directory this change.How Can I build this join between them. I tested your code  but i not able to go on .